# Navigation component - Hide navigation up icon and fragments label from the custom toolbar

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to use custom action bar(with custom logo and navigation up button) for my application.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

And set this tool bar in activity.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_auth)
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbarAuth)
toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

val mCustomView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_auth, null)
val mButtonBack= mCustomView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageBack)
toolbar.addView(mCustomView)
```

Custom action bar layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_actionbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:paddingStart="20dp"
android:paddingEnd="20dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageBack"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_actionbar_logo" />
```

But when I'm going to different fragments it's showing the default navigation up button and fragment label in the action bar. How can I remove/hide these?

I tried following ways as well, but those could not work for me.

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(false)
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason if you're using `toolbar.setupWithNavController` if you aren't using the default navigation up button and fragment label?

Comment: @ianhanniballake just want to handle action bar action with navigation. That's why I'm using this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toolbar.setupWithNavController()` method calls through to the `Toolbar` methods of  [`setNavigationIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#setnavigationicon_1) and [`setTitle()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)). Those methods know nothing about your custom icon or title - they only update the built in navigation icon and title.

That means that `toolbar.setupWithNavController()` is not something you should ever be calling.

Instead, if you want your custom Toolbar layout to react to Navigation changes, you'll want to follow the guide for [listening for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) and use an [`OnDestinationChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener) to do whatever custom logic you want instead of calling `toolbar.setupWithNavController()`:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_auth)
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbarAuth)
val mCustomView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_auth, null)
val mButtonBack = mCustomView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageBack)
toolbar.addView(mCustomView)
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, arguments ->
    // Update the icon for your mButtonBack, etc.
}
```

If you just want the default behavior for the navigation up icon, you can call [`navigateUp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigateUp()) directly:

```
mButtonBack.setOnClickListener {
    navController.navigateUp()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In hiding the fragment label, you can try this

```
android:label=""
```

That worked for me.